# Why is $ not recognised in angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular

I have included this in my typings.json file:

```
    {
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160317120654",
    "systemjs": "registry:dt/systemjs#0.18.4+20160417155658",
    "jquery": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/jquery/jquery.d.ts#661fc869669af796c6048483e999dce5732eed72"
  }
}
```

and the structure looks like this :

[image]

But I'll get the error that $ is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use global variables such as `jQuery` in an **Angular2 TypeScript** model you can do the following:

```
import // omitted for brevity...

declare var jQuery; // Declare it outside the scope of your class.

export class FooBar {
   constructor() {
       jQuery('selector').blah(...); // Use it
}
```

I have used this a few times, but do so sparingly. It is certainly frowned upon... I have only used the fully qualified name `jQuery`, but I assume you could use `$` as well.

Comment: `app/app.component.ts(6,9): error TS1005: ';' expected.` where this is causing the error: `declare jQuery: any;`

Comment: Still jquery is not defined

Comment: How do I create a Plunker with typings.json setup?

Comment: I tried creating a plunker but I did not get it fixed with the right setup.

Comment: How can I test this I tried multiple things, like changing the $ into jQuery in index.d.ts  but no resultsa